# ValueError: time data '13 Aug 05' does not match format '%d %m %y'

Tags: python, python-datetime

Not sure why I'm getting this error when trying to parse a string into datetime.

This is the code I have:

```
date = datetime.strptime("13 Aug 05", '%d %m %y')
```

and it is raising this error:

```
ValueError: time data '13 Aug 05' does not match format '%d %m %y'
```

Comment: %m requires a number (1-12), not a string, AFAIK. The documentation doesn't tell you?

Answer (score 2):

```
date = datetime.strptime("13 Aug 05", '%d %b %y')
```

You need to use `%b`, not `%m`, because your string uses the month's 3-letter abbreviated name and not the zero-padded decimal number.